# what's the different between the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow and Certificate credentials

Tags: azure, office365, outlook-addin

I want to write a daemon service to visit customer office 365 resource by application identity, from document i found there are two ways to support it one is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds and the other is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials. I want to know what's the different between them and which is the beat solution to implement a daemon service.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, the only difference between them is that certificate credential provides a higher level of assurance. For example, you can control the expired time of the client_assertion you generated flexibly. Even it is leaked, the damage will be minimized based on the lifetime of client_assertion.(This is only suppose that HTTPS is not security). If the shared secret was leaked, we will not able to limit it before we detect it and disable the secret.

More detail about client credentials flow, you also can refer link below:

[Service to service calls using client credentials (shared secret or certificate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service)

Comment: thanks for your answer. So based on your opinion, is there any scenario that just can use client_credential? Since i run into one problem that request subscription failed with a service access token which based on the protocol here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds#get-a-token and the return error is reason="The access token is acquired using an authentication method that is too weak to allow access for this application. Presented auth strength was 1, required is 2.";error_category="invalid_token"

Comment: It seems that service require more security method to acquire the token. For example, using the certificate(refer [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/iwilliams/2016/09/12/what-is-aobo/)).

Comment: yeah, I had the same idea, so i create certificate and change the manifest file, but still failed when call subscription with the access token.

Comment: i found the root cause, since i used the scope https://outlook.office.com and https://graph.microsoft.com at the same time, but seams /token api doesn't support it, so i just got an access token without valid scope. i think msft document enrich this case, since at other apis we could add multiple scopes at one times.

Comment: What's the **audience** in the token? Did it match the resource you were using?

Comment: after changed it to single scope, the audience is correct which is  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com".

I have another question about office addin id token, link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/inside-the-identity-token  introduce about the inside in the id token, i want to know which part of them can be used to identify one domain/org? what's the different between "iss" and "appctxsender"?